# How do I clear the timefield selection?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

```
                    {
                        xtype: 'timefield',
                        fieldLabel: Locale.gettext( 'End Time' ),
                        hidden: _self.hideEndTime,
                        editable: _self.editableEndTime,
                        listeners: {
                            change: function( t, newVal ) {
                                var btnCnt = t.previousSibling('fieldcontainer').query('button[pressed=true]');
                                if( btnCnt.length < 2 ) {
                                    t.previousSibling( 'timefield' ).setMaxValue( newVal );
                                } else {
                                    t.previousSibling( 'timefield' ).setMaxValue( '' );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

If one item has been selected in the drop-down of 'tiemfield', the item will be highlight. I am trying to clear/reset this, but the reset only reset the text field, and the the item that I previously selected is still highlighted. Is there any why to reset the drop-down?

Comment: [I made a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cm8) to see if i could replicate the issue, however, I get the expected behavior in the fiddle.  Would you be able to modify/create a fiddle that replicates your issue?

Comment: @weeksdev Actually, you can get this strange behavior. Since it's 4.1 framework in my project, I just simply change the version in the fiddle that you created, and it happens. I believe it's a bug, but I cannot change the Ext version, so I'm looking for some work around.

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me with all versions of ExtJS from 4.0.7 to 5.0.1. Maybe it's a browser thing, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue in 4.1 in the fiddle.

A work around I was able to come up with is to `refresh` the `timepicker` after resetting.

`myTimeField.getPicker().refresh()`

[And here is a working fiddle with the fix](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cnd)